# Making text larger without changing size of superscript?

Tags: plotting, graphics, text-formatting

I have the following plot:

```
    test1 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 1000}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, 
    Style[Row[{Subsuperscript["N", "W", "Post"]}], FontSize -> 30, 
     Black]}, Frame -> True]
```

I am trying to change the frame label such that the letter "N" is sufficiently larger than its corresponding Subsuperscript. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen `ScriptSizeMultipliers`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style each element of the Subsuperscript independently:

```
Subsuperscript[
  Style[a, FontSize -> 20, FontColor -> Blue], 
  Style[b, FontSize -> 10, FontColor -> Red], 
  Style[c, FontSize -> 12, FontColor -> Gray]]
```

**Edit to clarify usage as FrameLabel**

```
Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 1000}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, 
                 Subsuperscript[
                   Style["N", FontSize -> 35, FontColor -> Red, FontFamily -> "Alegreya SC"], 
                   Style["W", FontSize -> 10], 
                   Style["Post", FontSize -> 14, FontSlant -> Italic]]}, 
  Frame -> True]
```

Comment: For some reason, that did not work when I applied it to the frame label. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: I was able to adjust the size, color, and font-family of the FrameLabel. So, no, I don't know why it's not working for you. What version of Mathematica are you using? How exactly did you try it? I will say that in your original code the outer Style and the Row are unnecessary, but I don't think that would be the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works now.